# how to solve this issue with google ads flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart-pub, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to add google mobile ads in my flutter app , and I face this exception every time
I run flutter clean then flutter pub get and nothing happens

```
Restarted application in ٢٬١٧٨ms.
E/flutter (16366): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadBannerAd on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
E/flutter (16366): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter (16366): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16366): #1      BannerAd.load (package:google_mobile_ads/src/ad_containers.dart:876:5)
E/flutter (16366): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16366):
```

===============================================

```
  // TODO: Add _isBannerAdReady
  bool _isBannerAdReady = false;
late BannerAd _bannerAd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initGoogleMobileAds();

    // ads 

    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (_) {
          setState(() {
            _isBannerAdReady = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
          _isBannerAdReady = false;
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );

    _bannerAd.load();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller!.dispose();
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<InitializationStatus> _initGoogleMobileAds() {
    return MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code ? or you can follow this link : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter#6

Answer (score 0):

Have you called this code stuff. (BannerAd obj)

```
obj.load();
```

Comment: ,Yes i did you can see this is initstate  i will put it above

Comment: MobileAds.instance.initialize(); -- put this line in Main.dart file void main().